# Hashtable key syntax to refer to embedded hashtable element

Tags: powershell, hashmap, hashtable, powershell-2.0

Assuming that I have a hashtable:

```
$tokens = @{
    Id=9999; 
    Title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    Author=@{Name="John Doe"; Email='john.doe@foo.xyz'};
    Analyst=@{Name="Jane Doe"; Email='jane.doe@foo.xyz'}
}
```

And a template that I would like to populate, replacing the tokens (e.g. `__Title__`) with the corresponding hashtable's value:

```
/*
Author:     __Author.Name__ <__Author.Email__>
Analyst:    __Analyst.Name__ <__Analyst.Email__>
Request:    __Title__ [__Id__]
*/
...
```

Should become:

```
/*
Author:     John Doe <john.doe@foo.xyz>
Analyst:    Jane Doe <jane.doe@foo.xyz>
Request:    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [9999]
*/
```

Is there a way to refer to an embedded hashtable's elements in the 'parent' hashtable?  `$tokens['Author.Email']`, for example, doesn't work.

The code:

```
...
return [regex]::Replace( $template, '__(?<tokenName>\w+)__', {
  # __TOKEN__
  param($match)

  $tokenName = $match.Groups['tokenName'].Value

  if ($tokens[$tokenName]) {
    # matching token returns value from hashtable;
    works for simple keys `$tokens['Title']`, not complex keys `$tokens['Author.Name']`
    return $tokens[$tokenName]
  } 
  else {
    # non-matching token returns token
    return $match
  }
})
```

Comment: `$tokens.author.email` would be the email address. At least in PowerShell 3.0

Comment: What @Matt said. Also `$tokens['Author']['Email']`

Comment: @craig How do you mean though?

Comment: How would I go from getting `__Author.Email__` to `$tokens['Author']['Email']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

1. You need to fix the regular expression to actually match the nested properties. Right now it doesn't you need it to be `__(?<tokenName>[\w\.]+)__`
2. Use `Invoke-Expression` to dynamically expand the nested properties. Just build a string the represents the expression you want to evaluate. This is good because it doesn't rely on the model objects, `$tokens` and its properties, being hashtables at all. All it needs is for the properties to resolve on the objects that are there.

A short example is below. Note: if the template is coming from an unsecure source, be careful with this and sanitize the input first:

```
$tokens = @{
    Id=9999; 
    Title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
    Author=@{Name="John Doe"; Email='john.doe@foo.xyz'};
    Analyst=@{Name="Jane Doe"; Email='jane.doe@foo.xyz'};
    '3PTY' = "A";
    Test=@{'Name with space' = 'x' }
}

$template = @"
/*
Author:     __Author.Name__ <__Author.Email__>
Analyst:    __Analyst.Name__ <__Analyst.Email__>
Request:    __Title__ [__Id__]
3PTY: __"3PTY"__
Name:__Test.'Name with space'__
*/
"@

function Replace-Template {

    param ([string]$template, $model)

    [regex]::Replace( $template, '__(?<tokenName>[\w .\''\"]+)__', {
      # __TOKEN__
      # Note that TOKEN should be a valid PS property name. It may need to be enclosed in quotes
      # if it starts with a number or has spaces in the name. See the example above for usage.
      param($match)

      $tokenName = $match.Groups['tokenName'].Value
      Write-Verbose "Replacing '$tokenName'"
      $tokenValue = Invoke-Expression "`$model.$tokenName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

      if ($tokenValue) {
        # there was a value. return it.
        return $tokenValue
      } 
      else {
        # non-matching token returns token
        return $match
      }
    })
}

Replace-Template $template $tokens
```

Output:

> /*
>   Author:     John Doe 
>   Analyst:    Jane Doe 
>   Request:    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [9999]
>   3PTY: A
>   Name:x
>   */

Comment: Really-nice solution; +1.  I can see how `Invoke-Expression` could be dangerous.  Any recommendations on how to sanitize the template?

Comment: @craig Actually, I think its fine, as long as the token names are restricted to A-Z,a-z,0-9,_, and .. I don't think there's anyway to break out of the expression context. I was thinking the token name regex was a little more expansive.

Comment: I'm passing `$tokens` as a `HashTable` parameter, so I modified your code to `Invoke-Expression "\`$tokens.$tokenName"`.  Otherwise, it works exactly as I would like.  As an aside, is the backtick character syntactic sugar for `$()`?

Comment: Backtick is the escape character. You want to evaluate an expression like `$tokens.Author.Name`. If we don't escape the $ then it also interpolates $tokens giving you something like `System.Collections.Hashtable.Author.Name` which is not what you want to evaluate. See my update. I modified it to take another parameter, the "model" for the template.

Comment: FYI this script has a bug:
$tokenValue = Invoke-Expression "`$model.$tokenName" throws "Missing property name after reference operator." with certain token names.

Changing it to:
 $tokenValue = $model.Get_Item($tokenName)

...works

Comment: @ThomasJohnson For the example given, I'm pretty sure this worked when I wrote it and it works for me now. The suggested fix breaks it for the scenario of accessing subproperties that the OP asked for (e.g. Author.Name).

Comment: @mike-z it Hmmm - try it with a $tokenName starting with a numeric character

Comment: $tokens = @{}; $tokens.Add("3PTY", "pop"); $template = "This or that __3PTY__ blah blah'/>"; Replace-Template $template $tokens;
Replace-Template $template $tokens;   ...you end up getting: Missing property name after reference operator.  (There are underscores wrapping the tokenName in the $template assignment call, but they don't show up in the comment)

Comment: @ThomasJohnson Ah I see. Yes there is a restriction here that the template properties have to have valid powershell "simple" property names which can't start with a number. However, I made a small tweak to allow the quote characters, which would allow you to quote those in the template. See the updated code/example.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reference the element with dot notation

```powershell
$tokens.author.email
```

Then you could do things like this as well if you wanted to check if the name was empty for example. **Note** that there is a caveat: Author should exist for this to work exactly as intended.)

```powershell
If(!$tokens.author.name){$tokens.author.name = "Awesome Sauce"; }
Write-Host ("Author Name: {0}" -f $tokens.author.name)
```

You can also use hashtable notation as suggested by [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist)

```powershell
$tokens['Author']['Email']
```

**Dynamic replacement**

You use the word dynamic but I am not sure how far you want to take that. For now lets assume that the `$tokens` elements all exist and we are going to replace the text from a here-string.

```powershell
$text = @"
/*
Author:     __Author.Name__ <__Author.Email__>
Analyst:    __Analyst.Name__ <__Analyst.Email__>
Request:    __Title__ [__Id__]
*/
"@

$text -replace "__Author\.Name__",$tokens.Author.Name -replace "__Author\.Email__",$tokens.Author.Email `
        -replace "__Analyst\.Name__",$tokens.Analyst.Name -replace "__Analyst\.Email__",$tokens.Analyst.Email `
        -replace "__Title__",$tokens.Title -replace "__Id__",$tokens.Id
```

But I feel you mean *more* dynamic since all of this requires knowing information about the `$Tokens` and the the source string. Let me know how we stand now. We could get deeper with this.

**Lets get freaky**

Let say you know that the hashtable `$tokens` and the source `$text` have values in common but you don't know the names of them. This will dynamically populate text based on the key names on the hashtables. Currently this only works if there is only one hashtable depth.

```powershell
ForEach($childKey in $tokens.Keys){ 
    If($tokens[$childKey] -is [System.Collections.Hashtable]){
        ForEach($grandChildKey in $tokens[$childKey].Keys){ 
            Write-Host "GrandChildKey = $childKey"
            $text = $text -replace "__$childKey\.$($grandChildKey)__", $tokens.$childKey.$grandChildKey
        }
    } Else {
        $text = $text -replace "__$($childKey)__", $tokens.$childKey
    }
}

$text
```

**Something else**

This borrows from [mike z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517852/mike-z) suggestion about `Invoke-Expression` as it makes less guess work involved.

```powershell
$output = $text
$placeHolders = $text | Select-String '__([\w.]+)__' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object{$_.matches} | ForEach-Object{$_.Value}
$placeHolders.count
$placeHolders | ForEach-Object {
    $output = $output -replace [regex]::Escape($_), (Invoke-Expression "`$tokens.$($_ -replace "_")")
}
$output
```

Search the `$text` for all strings like **something**. For every match replace that text with its dot notation equivalent.

Output from either samples should match what you have for *Should become:*

Comment: How would I dynamically construct `$token.author.name` from values found in the template file?

Comment: Ah so I understand now. Can you show me a sample of some text for reference? This would not be hard to do. Sample will help give you context.

Comment: The text is in the question, but `Author:     __Author.Name__ <__Author.Email__>` should get converted to `Author:     John Doe <john.doe@foo.xyz>`

Comment: @craig Need to see what you are looking for. Answer now would get you your results but are you looking for something actually dynamic where the values are not hard coded?

Comment: The second option is better as doesn't require as much knowledge of `$tokens` hash and the template file.

Comment: @craig. Ok if that is in the right direction lets see if we can take it a step further.